# Changing size of square symbol to bullet symbol

Tags: symbols, amsmath, math-operators, boldsymbol

Is it possible to resize the `\blacksquare` command to the size of the `\bullet` command?

Additionally, is it possible to resize `\bullet` to `\circ`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- we create a variable for the width of `\bullet`
- we use `resizebox`

  ```
   \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \begin{document}
   \newlength{\mylength}
   \settowidth{\mylength}{$\blacksquare$}
   \the\mylength : $\blacksquare$
   \settowidth{\mylength}{$\bullet$}
   \the\mylength : $\bullet$
   \resizebox{\mylength}{!}{$\blacksquare$}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Several packages have these options. For example, `MnSymbol`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$a\circ b\bullet c\filledsquare d$

\end{document}
```

Slightly different is `fdsymbol`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fdsymbol}

\begin{document}

$a\circ b\bullet c\smallblacksquare d$

\end{document}
```